# How to reference a primary key in Ms Access VBA behind a report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to reference the Primary key on the continuous long summary report on my VBA code see below so that I get the correct results per total. The report was combined using domain functions, there is no ISSUE here in terms of performance all is perfect even if there are huge queries to do the actual calculations.

The report has grouped sales data for each salesman coming from unrelated tables & queries, thanks the domain functions has helped to construct this report accurately and with quality performance.

**Problems:**

I want now to have the final total for all salesmen, but if I reference the subtotal per each salesman, it only picks the value for the first salesman throughout, that is why I want to reference the primary which is based from the salesmen table and visible on the report. On the report I’m using this code below on-load event:
VBA Code

```
Me.txtsalestotal = Me.finalTotal
```

I'm putting the code above behind the report, but it keeps on picking the same value for one salesman to all salesmen, that's I why a primary key referencing is required here.

I think if I can be helped to know how to reference the primary key (which is Visible on the report) on the above code, then it will sort out this problem for good.

Comment: I now getting =Sum([txtfinalsales) I get a value on the report any idea to resolve this

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. It should be calculated when needed. The primary key for what? Perhaps you need another domain function expression.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to sum a calculated control,if I do not use SUM it works okay , the moment I change to sum an error pops up

Comment: Aggregate functions must reference a field, not a control.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my well researched answer to this problem:

Because of the domain functions that were used to summarize the report, then the sum function is now rendered irrelevant, meaning it can never be used on a non-bound control unless a control is bound directly to the record source in this case a query.
Solution

(1) Create a new control from any of participating tables with the correct data type in this numbers

(2) Include this control as part of the main record source query, the one which supplies the main data to the report in question.

(3) In the main report assign this control with the un-bound calculate value as its record source, Ms Access will treat it as a normal native control like any other queries controls.

(4) Then to have the cumulative figures just apply the in-belt report running total and hide it

(5) Finally add another control in the page footer and then reference the hidden control, problem solved!